# Looking for a punch / cutting die set for Aleko SGM01 Press

Tags: fabric

I purchased an [Aleko SGM01](http://www.alekoproducts.com/ALEKO-SGM01-Heavy-Duty-Hand-Press-p/grommetset-ap.htm) press with 5 grommet dies but I was also looking for a punch / cutting die set to put the holes in the fabric.  I have hammer-type punches now and would like to get away from that, is there anything out there?  Even if it's for another press I can look to see if the threads are teh same.

Thanks!

Comment: This reads like a product recommendation question which is off topic for our site. Otherwise your question is "do such products exist" which I am sure it yes.

Comment: @Matt This seems a bit more like a "how do I find a compatible lens cap for my DSLR" you'd see on [Photography.se]. I could be wrong, but that's what I get out of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are hole-punching dies for grommet machines. Specifically, they're sold as cutting dies for grommet machines, as you've mentioned, and also hole-piercing dies. They screw in to the press the same way the grommet dies do.

Unfortunately, the threading for the attachment of the die to the press is not universal, there can be differences between brands according to user reports. On top of that, ALEKO doesn't include any specs to go by (or even a product manual), making it more difficult to answer if Stimpson-compatible dies, for instance, will work with this product.

A cutting die for your size (#2 for instance), will work, in theory, on your press, but you may have to try to obtain one from different manufacturers. ALEKO themselves do not supply anything other than the 5 grommet dies #0-4.

[I have asked ALEKO](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wkpzXtXJ9pE), on the only outlet where it seems they reply publicly to users, whether or not additional dies are compatible.